# Is it possible to use a PEM format certificates in Java?

Tags: java, tls1.2

I'm looking for a way to import PEM format keys, such as what Apache uses, without calling keytool or an external tool.

Specifically, I am trying to create an SSLServerSocket. If another implementation such as NIO allows this, that would also be an option.

Comment: Where are you importing the keys and why can't you call keytool or use OpenSSL?

Comment: It's possible to use the two utilities, but the keys are located in two separate PEM format files and are updated automatically and without warning. Essentially I'm trying to create a KeyStore from a public_key.pem and a private_key.pem

Comment: You can't use them directly, but you can convert them to a PKCS#12 keystore with the OpenSSL tool, and either use that directly from Java or convert it to a JKS keystore. There are several questions here about how to do that.